# Making "states" in transitions fsm package more "stateful"

Tags: python, transition

I am using [Transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions), a very useful FSM tool for python. I would like to make the states more, um, stateful... so that variables can be local to states, and their values changed when the state is entered or left. I am ending up with a fair number of instance variables in the machine - I really want some of those values in the state (how long have I been in this state, for example). They aren't attributes of the model, they are attributes of progress through the states.

I wonder if there is a 'best way' to do this? Subclass State?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a 'best way' but a reasonable approach depends on what you want to achieve. You can either a) subclass State, b) decorate initialised states or c) manually initialise (subclassed) states and pass these to the machine.

**A)** If every state has the same attributes you can subclass states as you suggested:

```
import transitions.extensions.nesting as nesting


class CounterState(nesting.NestedState):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CounterState, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.entered = self.exited = 0

    def enter(self, event_data):
        self.entered += 1

    def exit(self, event_data):
        self.exited += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return "State {0} has been entered {1} times and exited {2} times".format(self.name, self.entered, self.exited)


class CounterMachine(nesting.HierarchicalMachine):

    @staticmethod
    def _create_state(*args, **kwargs):
        return CounterState(*args, **kwargs)

machine = CounterMachine(states=['A', 'B'], initial='A')

a = machine.get_state('A')
b = machine.get_state('B')

print(a) # >>> State A has been entered 0 times and exited 0 times
machine.to_B()
print(a) # >>> State A has been entered 0 times and exited 1 times
print(b) # >>> State B has been entered 1 times and exited 0 times
```

I have used `NestedMachine` here because `_create_state` is not available in `Machine` so far. **Update**: Starting from version `0.4.4` it is also available for `Machine`.

**B)** Another approach involves some decoration of the initiated state objects by the model:

```
from transitions import Machine


class Model(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=['A', 'B'], initial='A', 
                               before_state_change='exit_state',
                               after_state_change='enter_state')
        # loop through all the states and attach attributes
        for state in self.machine.states.values():
            state.entered = 0
            state.exited = 0

    def enter_state(self):
        # retrieve the state object by name
        self.machine.get_state(self.state).entered += 1

    def exit_state(self):
        self.machine.get_state(self.state).exited += 1


def print_state(state):
    print("State {0} has been entered {1} times and exited {2} times".format(state.name, state.entered, state.exited))

m = Model()

a = m.machine.get_state('A')
b = m.machine.get_state('B')

print_state(a)
m.to_B()
print_state(a)
print_state(b)
```

**C)** In cases where every state has to be treated individually, you can initiate the states manually and pass the instances to the machine instead of the names:

```
from transitions import Machine, State


class TicketState(State):

    def __init__(self, name, tickets):
        super(TicketState, self).__init__(name)
        self.tickets = tickets


class Model(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # Using our own state
        a = TicketState('A', 10)

        # Setting tickets ourselves
        b = State('B')
        b.tickets = 3

        self.machine = Machine(self, states=[a, b], initial='A',
                               before_state_change='decrease_tickets')

    def tickets_left(self):
        return self.machine.get_state(self.state).tickets > 0

    def decrease_tickets(self):
        s = self.machine.get_state(self.state)
        s.tickets -= 1
        if s.tickets < 0:
            raise Exception('No Tickets left!')
        print("State {0} has {1} tickets left.".format(s.name, s.tickets))

m = Model()
m.to_B() # >>> State A has 9 tickets left.
m.to_A() # >>> State B has 2 tickets left.
```

The amount of attributes and names could differ here of course. Instead of using the machine callback `before_state_change`, you can also pass `on_enter/exit` callbacks to the `State` object to treat each state individually during transitions. Or subclass `State.enter(self, event_data)` if you just require a set of different state types like `TimedState` and/or `CounterState`.

Comment: This isn't the usual interpretation of state-local variables. What you're proposing is variables that are persistent: when you enter a state, it still has the same variables as last time. Usually, you put variables into a state to make sure they'll be freshly initialized each time the state is entered, which this solution **doesn't** do. I'm not sure if it's what the OP wanted but I thought I should comment because this suggestion led me down the wrong alley completely.

Comment: @DanHule: good remark. In transitions, state instances are persistent. OP stated "..., and their values changed **when the state is entered or left.**" which (may falsely) implied for me that those are not scoped/temporal attributes. For *local/temporal/scoped* states [this](https://github.com/aleneum/rsbhsm/blob/master/rsbhsm/rsbhsm.py#L99) might be helpful. You can pass a class or classpath which will be used to initialize an object every time the state is entered.